# Removing parent directories from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, pseudocode

Suppose I have a folder structure like this:

- Root

  - Folder1

    - Folder 4
  - Folder2

    - Folder3

      - Folder5
  - Folder 6

I've got an array containing all the paths:

```
let paths = ['/root/','/root/folder1/','/root/folder2','/root/folder2/folder3'...
```

What I would like to accomplish is to remove the parent directories which have children recursively so I'd end up with this:

```
let paths = ['/root/folder1/folder4','/root/folder2/folder3/folder5','/root/folder6'];
```

Don't worry this isn't for homework or anything, just me getting stuck on my personal project :D

If you can answer with pseudocode (or even better JavaScript) that would be cool.

Comment: Do these files exist, or are the only strings? I’m asking because if you could actually check these against the file system, you’d be able to find out if the folder had any folders in it, and thus it was the last child.

Comment: Umm, do you want the paths which don't contain children?

Comment: They are only strings

Comment: I added another example, I hope it clears your question Ele

Comment: is the data sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the array contains some string which starts with the given path. Then filter that item out.

```js
var paths = ['/root/', '/root/folder1/', '/root/folder2', '/root/folder2/folder3/', '/root/folder1/folder4', '/root/folder2/folder3/folder5'],
    result = paths.filter((p, i, a) => !a.slice(i + 1).some(o => o.startsWith(p)));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was what I wanted.
I thought I needed some complex loops lol
I didn't even know about filter
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in different way by using `filter` & `some` API instead

```js
    let paths = ['/root/', '/root/folder1/', '/root/folder1/folder4/', '/root/folder2', '/root/folder2/folder3', , '/root/folder2/folder3/folder5', , '/root/folder6/'];

console.log(paths.filter((path) => {
        return !paths.some((indexPath) => { return path !== indexPath && indexPath.indexOf(path) > -1 });
}));
```